# AWS: Route 53 Configuration

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have created two instances in AWS (one is Live & other is Backup). My website is hosted on Live Instance. I have configured Route 53, Health checks & Hosted zones on default settings. Also have added both Instances to load balancer, and the status is "InService" for both the Instances.

For the Live Instance, Public IP & Elastic IP is same. For Backup Instance, Public IP is different from live, and Elastic IP is null.

What I want to achieve is, when my Live Instance "status check" or "Health check" fails, then Backup Instance should get activate.

Currently when I Manually stop my Live Instance for testing purpose, the backup Instance should get activate. but it doesn't happen. Please let me know if I am missing any steps.

Answer (score 2):

What you actually have to do is setting up the DNS entry in Route 53 as DNS Failover.

When you add two instances to a load balancer, what it does is it spread the load across your two instances. If an instance fails ELB health check, the instance will automatically be removed from the ELB and all traffic will be sent to the remaining instance.

If you want the DNS to send all traffic to only one server and only use the second server as backup (as you mentioned in your question), then you should use DNS Failover: [Amazon Route 53 Health Checks and DNS Failover](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html)

You can also do a DNS failover to ELB endpoints: [Amazon Route 53 Adds ELB Integration for DNS Failover](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-route-53-elb-integration-dns-failover/)